# Difference between google_project_iam_* and other google_*_iam_* resources

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-iam

When I replace `google_service_account_iam_member` [here](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/04ba18b714a80c860f10b11f345f49ff) with `google_project_iam_member` it still works. Which makes me think that `google_project_iam_*` provides more broad permissions: permissions that target any so to say target, be it a service account or whatever. And it seems like it's best to avoid it if there is a more specific resource. How do I know if there's a more specific resource? To be more specific, the other roles in the gist are:

- `roles/compute.osLogin`
- `roles/compute.osAdminLogin`
- `roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor`

But I'd like to understand how do I do this generally. Or maybe I'm missing something?

**UPD** I just thought that maybe [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.osAdminLogin) might be the hint:

> Lowest-level resources where you can grant this role: Instance

But with `google_compute_instance_iam_member` it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Resource `google_service_account_iam_member` allows you to add members that can be used by the service account that is getting access. In [this example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_service_account_iam#google_service_account_iam_member), SA is getting the possibility to use default GKE SA :

```
data "google_compute_default_service_account" "default" {
}

resource "google_service_account" "sa" {
  account_id   = "my-service-account"
  display_name = "A service account that Jane can use"
}

# Allow SA service account use the default GCE account
resource "google_service_account_iam_member" "gce-default-account-iam" {
  service_account_id = data.google_compute_default_service_account.default.name
  role               = "roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"
  member             = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.sa.email}"
}
```

On the other side the resource `google_project_iam_member` grants access for identities to all resources in the project. With this example you will grant admin access to all Google Storage Buckets:

```
resource "google_service_account" "sa" {
      account_id   = "my-service-account"
      display_name = "A service account that Jane can use"
    }

resource "google_project_iam_member" "project" {
  project = "your-project-id"
  role    = "roles/storage.admin"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.sa.email}"
}
```

The last option that you mentioned in the update is `google_compute_*_iam_member` which grants access on the resource level. That's why, when you will run this code sample you will grant admin access to only one Google Storage Bucket:

```
resource "google_service_account" "sa" {
  account_id   = "my-service-account"
  display_name = "A service account that Jane can use"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket" "example" {
  name          = "example"
  location      = "US"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_member" "member" {
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.example.name
  role = "roles/storage.admin"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.sa.email}"
}
```

To follow the least privilege role assignment you should grant access to the specific Google service with the resources `google_compute_*_iam_member`. You can find these resources in the specific category in the Terraform registry. For example, I am resource for the storage bucket is placed in the `Cloud Storage` -> `Resources` ->  [`google_storage_bucket_iam`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/storage_bucket_iam):

[image]

Comment: So as I suspected `google_project_iam` gives permissions for all the project resources (I like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61878052/52499) explanation, and some relevant information can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#resource), about project permissions being inherited). And more specific permissions are usually preferred. As for the target of a role (on which resource to grant a role), there's probably no easy way to find out.